# how to fetch which employee is working on which project in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 emp_id project_id
 3       2
 3       3
 7       1
 7       2
 7       3
 7       4
 3       27
 7       32
 3       31
 8       2
 8       3
 9       2
 9       3
```

Above is table of works on.  How to fetch which employee is working on which project in mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT emp_id, GROUP_CONCAT(project_id)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp_id] => 3
            [GROUP_CONCAT(project_id)] => 2,3,2,3,27,31,2,3,2,3
        )

)

Comment: i think  solution is not desired

Comment: @wasim What is the desired result then?

Comment: I think you need to replace emp_id with project_id

Comment: i need something like Array ( [emp_id] => 7 [project_id] => 1,2,3,4,32  )

Comment: Thanks Giorgos Betsos , your solution was right i missed to put group By clause in my query , Appreciate your quick response !!!